# Rails saving nested model association, has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to  :project,                    :inverse_of => :tasks 
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project 
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :workspace,            :inverse_of  => :projects
  has_many :tasks,                  :inverse_of => :project, 
                                    dependent: :destroy,
                                    autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :workspace 
end
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many                  :projects,          inverse_of: :workspace,
                                                dependent: :destroy,
                                                autosave: true
  has_many                  :tasks,             through: :projects
end
```

I am able to save the child object 'project' from 'workspace'. But I can't save the grandchild object 'task' from 'workspace'. What's wrong? How can I do that **without additional** '.save' calls? I don't want to call *@p.save*

```
####child####
@w = Workspace.first
@p = @w.projects.new(name: "text")

@w.save
@p.new_record? #false, which is ok

###grandchild###
@w = Workspace.first
@p = @w.projects.first
@t = @p.tasks.new(name: "text")

@w.save
@t.new_record? #true, but should've been saved
```